# How do I hide a user that is logged into the server, from other users

Tags: linux, debian, users, linux-virtual-server

If I and another person where logged onto a server (a Debian server to be exact) and I wanted to prevent the other user or even other user from seeing that I am active and logged into the server, how would I do that? Is there a command that I can use? If further clarification is needed, let me know.

Comment: How would you normally check if a user is logged in?Using `w`? Or ?

Comment: If I wanted to check if a user is logged in, I would either use `w` or `who`

Comment: GAD3R all users are able to use sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much you can do apart replacing commands such as `w`, `who`, `ps` etc. with a doctored version (modified on the source and then recompiled) whose output hides the user, say, *huntert*.

That's the technique usually used by intruders who compromise a server.

Note that an experienced Unix user might still be able to spot your presence by telltale signs, but this technique should fool the casual user -- or a lazy superuser.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't give them shell access.**

If they have code execution, there's very little you can do to pervent that. Replacing binaries like @dr01 suggests is pretty much useless, because they'll just upload a clean version and use that instead. You could patch the kernel syscalls, but that's a lot of work, and probably not enough on its own.

Replace their login shell in /etc/passwd with something that only gives them access to the bare minimum that they need to have access to.